# hardwired and wireless ceiling lights

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling

My husband saw a electrician hardwire on ceiling fixture that came with 2 or 3 identical lights that were not hard wired but were wireless. we can not find this light but want one and want to know how it works . this was on a diy or old house type show. can you help?

Answer (score 1):

When you say they were "wireless" you must mean wireless control, wireless on/off and dimming. There must have been a wire in the ceiling or in the wall to power the light. The only truly wireless lights are battery operated and not very bright and the batteries don't last very long.

Comment: Not true. Google "tesla coil florescent light". However, I doubt there are commercial, wireless lighting applications using this.

Answer (score 0):

Search for SkyLink they are a company that makes wireless switches, since 1990.  The switches aren't hardwired directly to any light fixtures- instead you install a receiver module at the light fixture, and the switch is the transmitter.